# Using HAML (in Ruby on Rails), is there a way to generate 50 nested DIVs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

To test something for CSS borders in nested DIVs, 50 DIVs need to be generated.
In other words, generate

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      ...  total 50 of them nested
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

because

```
- 50.times do
  %div
```

won't do, as they all will be parallel, not nested.

Comment: use recursion in a helper with content_tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplistic, but seems to work.

```
- 50.times do
  <div>
- 50.times do
  </div>
```

v2 - Still simplistic, but gives more options.

```
- 50.times do |i|
  != "<div style='border-style:#{cycle('dotted','dashed')}'>".rjust(i+35)
  = i
- 50.downto(1) do |i|
  != "</div>".rjust(i+35)
```

Comment: Donald, I spent 30 minutes (as an exercise) trying to figure out how to do the <div> indentation in HAML, and had just given up when I saw your "v2" revision. I wasn't even aware of the `!=` markup until this evening. Thanks for the lesson! P.S. changing the last line to `!= "</div>".rjust(i+7)` makes it perfect.

Comment: @Dave, I too was doing it for the challenge and was also unaware of `!=` ... almost gave up until I found this [cheatsheat](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/haml/).  This was a fun one!

Comment: good answer.  I didn't know you can put markup directly as "content"... that's interesting

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def recursive_divs(number)
    if number > 0
      number -= 1
      content_tag :div do
        recursive_divs(number)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And use it on your view:

```
= recursive_divs(50)
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're close. All you have to do is add 2 spaces for each iteration of the loop.

```
- 50.times do |i|
  ="#{' ' * (i*2)}"%div
```

The `' '  * (i*2)` part is making use of the fact that strings can be multiplied.

Comment: Thanks... Knew it was possible, but couldn't remember how to multiply strings.  Since the spacing was secondary to the nesting, I didn't spend a lot of time researching that.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DonaldSowell yeah the main thing to remember is that the string needs to come FIRST since it's a method call on string. If you put the number first and string second it wont work. But also, since this is HAML whitespace IS the nesting.

Comment: are you sure `="#{' ' * (i*2)}"%div` works?  I tried it and it doesn't work.  It will error out as `undefined local variable or method 'div' for #<#<Class:0x00000104842e48>:0x000001048410e8>`

Comment: sorry, I was just testing using irb to see if it would output the right # of spaces. I didn't consider the fact that it needs to be output to haml BEFORE being rendered.